# CSS font size not being respected

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I've got a font size set in a CSS class that is set to size 10px. It works fine on my PC and the other dev's PC, but when clients access the site they get a larger text size. We've checked their browser settings and text size is set to medium just like our PCs. This is an internal web app and all users (and us devs) use Internet Explorer 8.

What could overwrite our CSS settings that's outside of the web application? Are there any other browser or OS settings that could interfere?

Font size and family are:

```
  font-family:MS Sans Serif, Verdana; 
  font-size:10px !important;
```

Comment: which font-family you are using ?

Comment: what about their windoze text scaling settings? control panel -> display -> set custom text size

Comment: may be that font is not installed on your client pc or may be you are not  using web safe font

Comment: Font size and family are:

  font-family:MS Sans Serif, Verdana; 
  font-size:10px !important;

Answer (score 0):

Do your clients have "Intranet Settings" or "Compatibility View" enabled in IE?  They will make IE8 pretend to be IE7, which might account for the difference in rendering.

Comment: -1 from me because security settings should never affect the font-size

Comment: @meda: Then feel free to downvote IE itself, but not me.  :-)  The fact is that those settings will make IE8 render pages as though it were IE7, and that can certainly affect the font sizes.

Comment: Compatibility View is off. Turning it on actually fixes the issue. However, the company insists that it work without compatibility view on.

Comment: @Legion: In that case, you could try adding `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=7" >` to the HTML's `<head>`, or serving the pages with the `X-UA-Compatible: IE=7` HTTP header.  Either of those should force the same mode as Compatibility View.

Comment: That was the first thing we tried. Unfortunately it's not quite the same as compatibility view. It would have been nice if it worked, because I had to spend 3 days reworking the markup.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, make sure you use a CSS Reset to get to the common CSS denominator. :)
http://www.cssreset.com/
 - Pick one from the site above if you aren't using one.

After that, I'd suggest to set a default font size in your body {} selector.  If you use 62.5% you can then just use relative font sizes, specifically the em unit.  With 62.5% as the default, 1em = 10px.
e.g.

```
body
{
font-size: 62.5%;
}
```

This will work cross browser and is pretty standard.  HTH.

Comment: Tried the CSS reset. This would have been great if we used it from the beginning. But this application is a behemoth and when I add the reset, it breaks the design everywhere. Unfortunately, due to time constraints it's not viable.